# Is it possible for a hacker to find the value of a session variable on my server ?

Tags: php, variables, cookies, server

Is it possible for someone (hacker), to somehow get a hold of the value of a session variable that is active.

Comment: it's unlikely but possible.

Comment: Certainly, if you allow him... Sorry, this is _not_ meant as a joke! The issue with your question is that it is impossible to answer. We do not know your setup or code, nothing. How do you expect an answer from us?

Comment: @FelipeAlarcon Would you care to elaborate that statement?

Comment: This is – *probably* – a better fit on [security.se], given the focus on "security," rather than that of a "programming problem."

Comment: @arkascha As you mentioned, we don't know his setup so it's indeed possible. However if he's setup is good, it's unlikely... hard to answer this accurately without code.

Comment: @arkascha I'm creating a random  set of numbers for every session created (user logging in), and attaching it to a session variable, to secure some simple ajax request. (sorry if im not explaining it so well), but what is the best possible action to take in order to prevent a hacker from finding this value, and using it to his advantage ?

Comment: Sorry, if this belongs somewhere else, I'm a 17 year old developer, fairly new to this site.

Comment: The question is not _what_ you keep in a variable, but how you allow access to it. A variable without access by the code is useless, so there has to be some form of access. Everything that is accessible by your code _may_ be exposed. That is what depends on your code which we do not know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the normal course of events, the only information about a session available to the client is the session ID.

For data stored on the server (even if it connected to the session ID) to be visible to the client then you need either:

- To expose it explicitly
- To have a security vulnerability

Comment: Great: "To have a security vulnerability"... Which basically says: "back to square one".